# Erro de GROUP BY SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenho o seguinte exercicio:

> 6. Liste o código e nome do departamento, data de admissão mais nova e mais antiga de cada
>      departamento, ordenar pelo nome do departamento.

Consegui fazer o seguinte:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, max(jh.start_date), min(jh.start_date) from departments d
inner join job_history jh on jh.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id order by d.department_name;
```

Porém da o erro abaixo, gostria de saber porque ele acontece e como resolver.

> ```
> ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY
> 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> Erro na linha: 45 Coluna: 25
> ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual sua duvida? Fornecer apenas o enunciado não ajuda muito, edite a pergunta e forneça mais detalhes do que está tendo dificuldade.

Comment: Esse é o problema, fiz a resposta baseada no enunciado que eu coloquei descrito. Mas como sou iniciante nao sei por que o group by esta dando erro. Depois de algumas pesquisas eu descobri q a resolucao seria por group by mas nao entendo o erro...

Comment: Tente agrupar por todos os campos que vc colocou no select, pelo menos é como a maioria dos bancos trabalha.

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro:ORA-00934: a função de grupo não é permitida aqui
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 47 Coluna: 46

Comment: Tenta reproduzir seu banco de dados nesse site pra gente tentar te ajudar: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Tenta assim: `select d.department_id, d.department_name, max(jh.start_date), min(jh.start_date) from departments d
inner join job_history jh on jh.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id order by d.department_id, d.department_name;`

Comment: Meu BD é um que a oracle disponibiliza para download e testes, o Diagrama do mesmo esta disponivel em imagem

Comment: @R.Santos deu o mesmo erro amigo...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quando o group by é utilizado, você só pode colocar no select as colunas epecificadas no group by ou funções agregadoras (ex: max, min, sum).

Faz sentido, pois, de outra forma, o que o SGBD deveria retornar para departamentos que possuem o mesmo Id, mas nomes diferentes (supondo que o id não fosse a chave)? Nesse caso haveria mais de um valor para retornar, mas cada linha deve retornar apenas uma valor para o nome.

Se você agrupou por uma coluna, as outras podem ter valores distintos, e não faria sentido retorná-las.

Logo, no seu caso você teria que agrupar por código (id) e nome.

Answer (score 3):

Tente isso:

```
SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, MAX(jh.start_date), MIN(jh.start_date) 
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN job_history jh ON jh.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name ORDER BY d.department_name;
```